# Django comments - Ajax and CSRF failure

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json, csrf

I think this is different to other problems here, I've checked out answers and still no luck. Thanks for any help:

I have a list of News items (like a facebook feed) and there's a comment form attached to each one (using the django.contrib.comments app). It works fine normally.

BUT, I'm using a kind of AJAX 'infinite scroll' on the page - as you scroll, it loads the next set of News items and related comment form via AJAX. The comment forms on the newly-loaded news items don't work (it fails on CSRF validation).

It's obvious why - the {% csrf_token %} isn't passed to the JSON response that comes back, so the newly-loaded comment forms have no CSRF data.

I've tried using the set cookie method on the Django pages (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax), but doesn't seem to work and neither does trying the @csrf_exempt decorator to totally exclude CSRF.

Any suggestions how I can pass a csrf_token along with the returning JSON response? Or is there an alternative?

Here's the view:

```
def my_view(request):
    # the normal view gets a queryset of all Info items and returns them
    infos = Info.objects.all()
    ....

    # here's the AJAX part
    if request.GET.get('xhr') and page > 1:
        infos = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page')))
        objects_list = []
        for object in infos:
            objects_list.append(render_to_string('list/snippets/feed_li.html', {
                'object': object,
            }))

        json =  simplejson.dumps(objects_list, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is going to be to provide the CSRF token to your form via the JSON response you are returning. I believe you can get the CSRF token programatically by calling `django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)` and then including that value in your ajax response.

The other option I can think of is to disable the CSRF protection for that view.

Answer (score 0):

First check out if you forgot to include {% csrf_token %} in the 'list/snippets/feed_li.html';

Second, to make the csrf token function properly, you must use RequestContext or manually generate the token and add it to the context variable when rendering the template(see [Django csrf ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/)). Thus, replace the line:

```
objects_list.append(render_to_string('list/snippets/feed_li.html', {
    'object': object,
}))
```

with:

```
''' from django.template import RequestContext ''' 
objects_list.append(render_to_string('list/snippets/feed_li.html', \
    RequestContext(request, {'object':object})
))
```

or:

```
''' from django.core.context_processors import csrf '''
vars = {}
vars.update(csrf(request))
vars.update({'object':object})
objects_list.append(render_to_string('list/snippets/feed_li.html', vars))
```